# Как правильно сверстать такой элемент?

Tags: html, css

Как правильно сверстать такой элемент?
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: Какой именно элемент из представленных на картинке? Ряд карточек, с увеличенной центральной карточкой? Покажите ваш код и скажите, что конкретно у вас не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот набросал 
http://jsfiddle.net/e445kxzm/

html

```
<div class="conteiner">
     <div class="item">
         <div class="item-head"></div>
         <div class="item-body"></div>
         <div class="item-foot"></div>
     </div><!-- 
--><div class="item item-best">
         <div class="item-head"></div>
         <div class="item-body"></div>
         <div class="item-foot"></div>
</div><!-- 
--><div class="item">
         <div class="item-head"></div>
         <div class="item-body"></div>
         <div class="item-foot"></div>
   </div>    
</div>
```

css

```
.item{
    margin: 25px auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 33.33%;
    background: #37AB87;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.item-best{
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```